# Static Factory Methods Return Types

Tags: java

This is an excerpt from this popular book Effective Java:

> The class of the object returned by a static factory method need not even exist
>   at the time the class containing the method is written. Such flexible static factory
>   methods form the basis of service provider frameworks, such as the Java Database
>   Connectivity API (JDBC).

I tried testing it out as follows:

```
class Student {
    String name;
    int id;

    public Student(String s, int i) {
        name = s;
        id = i;
    }

    public static DegreeWorks details(Student s) {
        return new DegreeWorks(s);
    }
}
```

However, it gives a compile-time error (as it should) that the class DegreeWorks doesn't exist. So, what's the point about the class being returned by a static method not even having to exist while the class containing the method is written? Please explain.